# JavaScript callback in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, callback, typescript

I'm trying to implement a JavaScript callback with namespace within a TypeScript file. I thought that it is possible to copy 1:1 JavaScript code within TypeScript, but the compiler in Visual Studio throws a lot of errors.

Should I change the JavaScript to TypeScript with the lambda expression or is there a possibility to disable the error messages?

```
 ; (function (scope, $, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    scope.ajaxPost = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'PassData/PostAjax',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'jsonMessage': "I was passed successfully" },
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (returnVal) {
                alert(returnVal);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failed");
            },
        });
        return false;
    };
}(
    some.namespace('my.namespace.Calllback'),
    jQuery
));
```

Comment: "but the compiler in Visual Studio throws a lot of errors." -- What errors?

Comment: It's rare that you can simply copy JavaScript code into a TypeScript file and have it compile with no errors, especially if you have certain compiler directives turned on like `noImplicitAny`.  What are the specific error messages you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler will throw errors because of mismatching types and that's a good thing  in the migration progress of JS to TS.

But the important thing is: if the code has a valid syntax the TypeScript compiler will emit the JavaScript (even though the errors are shown). So you can use TS and gradually update your code.

If you need help with a specific error, please update your question or post another one.